# iCloud control panel in Windows is missing Mail, Contacts, Calendars, and Tasks tab

Tags: icloud, windows

Have Windows 7 with Outlook 2007 linked to iCloud to sync calendars, tasks and contacts. works great.  Now I have to set up new Windows 7 with Outlook 2007. Installed iCloud for Windows, but when I start it the checkbox for "Mail, Contacts, Calendars, and Tasks" is missing.  Only have checkboxes for "iCloud Drive", "Photos", and "Bookmarks".  Every troubleshooting post just assumes the checkbox is there, and I just can't figure out why it is not. any ideas?
[image: Screenshot iCloud control panel Windows]

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't really know what the original problem was, I did find a workaround.

When trying to connect iCloud to Outlook I was using my PST file from my old machine, and the iCloud option to sync "Mail, Contacts, Calendar & Tasks" was missing.

I then deleted MS Office and reinstalled.  Now, before copying over my old PST file I tried to connect iCloud with the new, empty, PST file.... and it was now successful.  I was able to "see" my iCloud Contacts and Calendar.  So, far, so good...
I then copied over the old PST file, made it the default pst file, and deleted the "new, empty" pst file. Went into Outlook and everything was there... my mail, iCloud calendar, and iCloud Contacts.  Success.

Now, why did this work???  The ONLY thing I could think of was that, somehow, iCloud knew my old pst file was already connected to iCloud so it didn't offer the option to connect to outlook.  As soon as I used a "new" pst file, iCloud showed me the option to connect to outlook.  Anyway, that's my theory.  Anybody have any other ideas about what might be happening?